# Vertical axis as function value

Tags: plotting

For a strictly increasing arbitrary function f[y], where y is the variable for the left hand side vertical axis(LHS) in the 2D plot, I wish to show its value using the vertical axis on the right hand side(RHS).
(x will be the variable for the horizontal axis.)

As an example, I wish to show the value of f[y=1] using the coordinate value of the RHS vertical axis, and it should be ticked on the same height as y=1 in the LHS vertical axis.

Since f[y] will be an arbitrary function, its increasing rate will be arbitrary, and therefore the scale for the RHS vertical axis will not be uniform.

I have seen some examples where the scale for the RHS vertical axis is uniform, just like the LHS vertical axis.
But I couldn't find any examples stated above.
I want to ask if this type of plotting is achievable in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is something like the following what you're looking for?

```
Plot[
    10 Sin[x],
    {x,0,Pi},
    Frame->True,
    FrameTicks->{
        {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Sqrt[#]&, #^2&}]},
        {Automatic, None}
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Carl, thank you for the answer! Yes this is what I am looking for, although I am not familiar with Charting`ScaledTicks at the moment. The example you kindly demonstrated is for f[y]=y^2. Is this type of plotting possible for any type of strictly increasing f[y], e.g., even for functions that are defined piece wise using Heaviside-theta functions that shows completely different behaviors depending on the y axis value?

Comment: I see. As long as I have numerically "good" definition of the inverse function,  it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to frame your plot, and as sometimes it could be difficult to use undocumented functions, you can use `AxesOrigin` and custom `Ticks`:

```
ticks[xmin_, xmax_] := Table[{i, NumberForm[Sqrt[i], {2, 2}]}, {i, xmin, xmax}];
pl = Plot[10 Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {Pi + 0.2, 0.}, 
Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}]
```

[image]

You can even modify the ticks marks if you do not want to they point outwards.

[image]

Or by using `Frame` but removing those unwanted axes:

```
ticks[xmin_, xmax_] := Table[{i, NumberForm[Sqrt[i], {2, 2}], {0, 0.005}}, {i, xmin, xmax}]; 
 Plot[10 Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, \[Pi] + 0.2}, {0, 10}}, 
 Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, False}}, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, ticks}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]